# Ponderación en PHP de notas de un curso

Tags: php

En PHP tengo un formulario que captura una serie de notas... estas notas van por método POST a un archivo PHP, donde a cada una de estas notas se le asigna un porcentaje sobre la nota final, por ejemplo:

```
NOTA 1: equivale al 20% de la nota final
NOTA 2: equivale al 30% de la nota final
NOTA 3: equivale al 50% de la nota final
```

¿Cómo puedo obtener la nota final con estos porcentajes?

Intenté haciendo algo como esto pero no me funcionó:

```
$final = (($nota1*20%)+($nota2*30%)+($nota3*50%));
echo "<br><br>Tu nota final es: " . $final;
```

Comment: Estás planteando mal la operación matemática. Multiplicar un número por 20 da ese número por 20, no el porcentaje, aunque lo acompañes del símbolo %. Haz lo siguiente, compártenos todo el código que tengas en relación a esto. Como recoges las notas, como las procesas y como las muestras además del formulario (solo el formulario) con el que las envías. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$final = $nota1 * 0.2 + $nota2 * 0.3 + $nota3 * 0.5;
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, preciso lo que necesitaba.

Answer (score 2):

Tienes que multiplicar por el porcentaje expresado en decimal, de la siguiente manera:

```
$final = ($nota1*0.2)+($nota2*0.3)+($nota3*0.5)
```

Los paréntesis no son necesarios, pero prefiero colocarlos por orden. También ten en consideración que antes debes asignar las variables:

```
$nota1 = $_POST['nota1'];
$nota2 = $_POST['nota2'];
$nota3 = $_POST['nota3'];
```

Dime si tienes alguna duda.

Comment: Una duda que me asalta. Si la variable viene de un input text, lo que tiene es una string y no un int, no?. Debería meterle un parseint a las $nota?.

Comment: Si mandas un type text, pero contiene solo números, PHP lo entiende como solo números. No es necesaria la conversión y recomendaría no hacerla ya que podría desordenar tu código.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración. No podía probarlo porque estaba trabajando. Un saludo.